# Fail to sort few different list using sorting library ng2-dnd

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, angular, angular2-routing

Im  using some nice and [simple drag-and-drop library from github](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd), and I have a view with 3 different buttons each presenting a list when its being clicked in the same place but NOT on the same time.

From some reason only the first list can be sorted but the other 2 re not...I can move the objects but they are not droppable so I cant change the order.

this is my html:

```
<div>
  <!-- list 1 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showFirstList()"
          class="md-primary">List 1
  </button>

  <!-- list 2 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="showSecondList()"
          class="md-primary">List 2

  </button>

  <!-- list 3 button -->
  <button md-button
          (click)="ThirdList()"
          class="md-primary">List 3

  </button>
</div>


        <md-content>

          <div *ngIf="showingListOne">
            <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-one']" [sortableData]="listOneToDisplay | async">
              <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listOneToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> name: {{item.name}}
              </div>
            </div><br><br>
          </div>


          <div *ngIf="showingListTwo">
            <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-two']" [sortableData]="listTwoToDisplay | async">
              <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listTwoToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>


          <div *ngIf="showingListThree">
            <div dnd-sortable-container [dropZones]="['zone-three']"  [sortableData]="listThreeToDisplay | async">
              <div class="list-bg" *ngFor="#item of listThreeToDisplay | async; #i = index" dnd-sortable [sortableIndex]="i">
                ID: {{item.id}} <p></p> age: {{item.age}}
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
          </div>

        </md-content>
```

this is my sorting-lists.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sorting-lists',
  styles: [require('./sorting-lists.css')],
  directives: [DND_DIRECTIVES],
  providers: [DND_PROVIDERS],
  template: require('./sorting-lists.component.html')
})

@Injectable()
export class MyCmp implements OnInit {

  listOneToDisplay  = this._myService.getFirstListData();
  listTwoToDisplay = this._myService.getSecondListData();
  listThreeToDisplay = this._myService.getThirdListData();

  showingListOne = false;
  showingListTwo = false;
  showingListThree = false;

  constructor(private _myService: MyService) {
  };


  public showFirstList(): void {
    this.showingListOne = true;
    this.showingListTwo = false;
    this.showingListThree = false;
  }

  public showSecondList(): void {
    this.showingListTwo = true;
    this.showingListOne = false;
    this.showingListThree = false;
  }

  public showThirdList(): void {
    this.showingListThree = true;
    this.showingListTwo = false;
    this.showingListOne = false;
  }

}
```

if someone can help me figure out why only the first one is sortable it will be blessed!!

thanks :)

Comment: put this code in plunkr so that it is easier to debug

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT2**: (According to your new version of the question):

Try to provide DND_PROVIDERS in the bootstrap of your application instead to provide it in your component. For more details take a look [here](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd#usage).

```
bootstrap(AppComponent, [
    DND_PROVIDERS // It is required to have 1 unique instance of your service
]);
```

---

You can also use [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula), which is the official Angular2 wrapper for [dragula](https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula).

**Install via npm**

**EDIT**: To use ng2-dragular with **angular 2.0.0-beta.15**, add the ng2-dragula package with a github link with the last commit before they switched to RC.1 in your `package.json`:

`ng2-dragula": "git://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula.git#0cdcd52b1a486609ed4b4a43465b1dac2bb1b007`

```
> npm install
```

**Usage**

Add the DragulaService to your components and add Dragula to your components directives.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'sample',
  directives: [Dragula],
  viewProviders: [DragulaService],
  template:`
  <div>
    <div class='wrapper'>
      <div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <div>You can move these elements between these two containers</div>
        <div>Moving them anywhere else isn't quite possible</div>
        <div>There's also the possibility of moving elements around in the same container, changing their position</div>
      </div>
      <div class='container' [dragula]='"first-bag"'>
        <div>This is the default use case. You only need to specify the containers you want to use</div>
        <div>More interactive use cases lie ahead</div>
        <div>Make sure to check out the <a href='https://github.com/bevacqua/dragula#readme'>documentation on GitHub!</a></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  `
})
class Sample {}
```

Comment: im not looking for angular 2 library, rather specifically angular 2.0.0-beta.15 and they dont support it

Comment: You can use ng2-draguar with the beta.15 version. Look at my updated answer.

Comment: iv added it to my dependencies and npm installed it, but when I add Dragula and DragulaService its not finding where to import it from

Answer (score 2):

I use either ng2-dragula (https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) or primeng (http://www.primefaces.org/primeng).

If I understand your sample, ng2-dragula should do the job.

Not sure if these work with the Angular2 version you need to use.

I hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng2-dnd`.

[ng2-dnd](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-dnd)

I had used it in angular2 beta and its quite easy and flexible to use.

Hope this helps.